# How to translate float3 to SIMD3<Float> (Xcode 11 Swift 5 giving depreciation warning with float3 and float4)

Tags: swift, xcode, floating-point

I am trying to get my code to be warning free. As I've just updated my Xcode and am know getting warning signs. I also have my attempted at fixing this below as well.

This is the code that is giving me the warnings:

**Code:**

```
extension float4x4 {
var translation: float3 {
    return float3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
}

init(translation vector: float3) {
    self.init(float4(1, 0, 0, 0),
              float4(0, 1, 0, 0),
              float4(0, 0, 1, 0),
              float4(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, 1))
 }
}

extension float4 {
  var xyz: float3 {
    return float3(x, y, z)
}
```

[image]

This is my attempted to translate this below:

**Code:**

```
extension SIMD4 {
var translation: SIMD3<Float> {
    return SIMD3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
}

  init(translation vector: SIMD3<Float>) {
    self.init(SIMD4<Float>(1, 0, 0, 0),
              SIMD4<Float>(0, 1, 0, 0),
              SIMD4<Float>(0, 0, 1, 0),
              SIMD4(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z))
  }
}

  extension SIMD4 {
    var xyz: SIMD3<Float> {
      return SIMD3<Float>(x, y, z) as! SIMD3<Float>
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're accidentally extending `SIMD4` when you really meant to extend `float4x4` (which, unlike `float3` and `float4`, is *not* deprecated).

Also, in your other extension, it should probably be `SIMD3<Scalar>`, not `SIMD3<Float>`, so that `xyz` will return a `SIMD3` that has the same type of `Scalar` as whatever `SIMD4` it is called on:

```swift
extension float4x4 {
    var translation: SIMD3<Float> {
        SIMD3(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
    }

    init(translation vector: SIMD3<Float>) {
        self.init(.init(1, 0, 0, 0),
                  .init(0, 1, 0, 0),
                  .init(0, 0, 1, 0),
                  .init(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, 1))
    }
}

extension SIMD4 {
    var xyz: SIMD3<Scalar> {
        SIMD3(x, y, z)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically, I have tried just to replace:

```
float3
```

with:

```
SIMD3<Float>
```

And the warning has been disappeared.

Comment: Yes, Apple has updated their vector types since this post was created. `Float3` has been deprecated and relaced with `SIMD3<Float>`, and `Float4` has been deprecated and replaced with `SIMD4<Float>`. (voted)